# Can't connect to Wi-Fi from my Phone

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

I new to Ubuntu, I'm sorry if his question is to basic, but I couldn't find any answers online.

So basically I use my Phone(Honor 6X) as a WI-Fi repeater to connect my PC to the Internet (This give a new network with a new name and password, so it's not like a usual repeater). 
This worked fine on Windows. But after I installed Ubuntu I can't connect to this network anymore. I also tried to connect over "Hidden Networks", but that didn't work either.

I hope some could help me.
Thanks

With this command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

I get:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I'm using USB Stick for Wi-Fi

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2357:0109  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04b4:6014 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0820 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Can you connect to something else?

Comment: Just tried it, but this didn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Are you using a USB dongle or a built-in wireless device?

Comment: Then post output of `lsusb`. It was hard to guess that you were using USB.

Comment: This is rtl8192eu chip. You need drivers But it depends on a kernel that you are using.